# Show information from a table in a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

This code gives no errors and when I run it it doesn't show anything in the data grid view, why not?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-5GVNUF2;Database=Censo;Integrated Security=True");
string consulta = "SELECT * FROM InformacionEquipos";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        conexion.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta, conexion);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adaptador.Fill(dt);
        dgvDatos.DataSource = dt;
        //conexion.Close();
}
```

I'm trying to show all the data from that table in a datagridview.

Comment: Note: an Adapter will open and close the connection for you, so you don't need the `conexion.Open();` line.

Comment: What is your runtime environment? Winforms? Webforms? Something else entirely? What's the .NET platform you're using - .NET "classic" - what version? - or .NET Core - again: what version?

Comment: .NET 7.0 Windows forms 17.7.6

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that `Form1_Load` is correctly hooked up to the Load event of your form. This can be done in the designer or by adding `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);` in the `Form1` constructor.

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
}
```

Or just override the OnLoad method:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnLoad(e);
  //getting the data logic
}
```

Comment: thank you very much I was able to solve it

Comment: @NayeliLopez then maybe consider "accepting" this answer